# Descending chain condition for radical ideals

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

For which integral domains $R$ (not filed) the ring $R[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ satisfies descending chain condition for radical ideals? I am not expert in Ring Theory and I need an answer to construct some examples in a different area of algebra. This question may have a trivial answer and so I apologize if it is meaningless or quite trivial.

P.S. Is there an infinite ring  without nonzero nilpotent element having the above property?

Comment: If $R$ is a domain and contains the integers, then the sequence $(x) \supset (x) \cap (x-1) \supset (x) \cap (x-1) \cap (x-2) \supset \cdots$ is a nonterminating descending chain of radical ideals.

Comment: @Graham Leuschke: Thank you, your example shows that there is no such an infinite  domain.

Comment: The same proof shows that there is no such domain for $n\geq 2$, right? Because $R[x_1,\dots,x_n]=R[x_1][x_2,\dots,x_n]$, and $R[x_1]$ is always an infinite domain. Then clearly for $n=1$ finite domains do have this property, answering the question.

Comment: Thank you for comments. What happens if we use commutative rings without nonzero nilpotent elements instead of domains?

Comment: Some quotient of $R[x_1]$ is an infinite domain, providing the desired example. (A chain of ideals in $Q[x_2,\dots,x_n]$ can be lifted to $R[x_1][x_2,\dots,x_n]$, where $Q$ is a domain which is an infinite quotient of $R[x_1]$.) So, it remains to consider the case $n=1$, which is not rich either.